# Android Project and Java / C++ Optimalizations

Tags: java, android, c++, arm

I have very simple loop which can be calculated by compiler and executed instantly. So, on Desktop Linux, if I compile it with -O0 it takes 1.6s and with -02 it takes 0.00001s.

However when I create Android Project, this loop takes 6s when running on Java and 2.5s when running in C++.

In Gradle App Project, I added -O2 to cppFlags and it seems to still perform the same.

I used Android 29 SDK on Android 24 platform (arm7a).

Am I missing something?

When I compile C++ app for x86 Android in vm, it executes 1.1s. Which means there are some optimalizations but not as good as on Desktop.

Here's the C++ code (same as Java code):

```
long l = 0;
for(long i = 1; i < 100000000; i++) {
    l++;
    l = l / i;
}
```

Comment: Is the code and test irrelevant to the question?

Comment: I've added the source code for the function it performs poorly